Can't use tuples with a 0 as the second variable in a tuple-enum in Python
I want to use an enum as a tuple for my Board-coordinates in my chess program like this:
    from enum import Enum
    class Pos(tuple, Enum):
        A1 = (0, 0)
        A2 = (0, 1)
        B1 = (1, 0)
        B2 = (1, 1)

However any coordinates that end in 0 raise a valueerror.
Example:
    print(Pos(1, 0))

return:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TuffGolem\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.3\scratches\scratch_6.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(Pos(1, 0))
          ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\TuffGolem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\enum.py", line 740, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\TuffGolem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\enum.py", line 1154, in __new__
    raise ve_exc
ValueError: 1 is not a valid Pos

It seems like the 0 is ignored and it is tried to instead use the enum with just the first number.
Initially i just incremented each value by 1 to solve the problem, so that there are no such cases where it ends in a 0. This seems more like a workaround than a solution though and doesn't work because i need to use the tuple as Coordinates in a Numpy-array (the Board). Does anyone know how i can use coordinates that end with 0?
Ethan Furmanns Solution worked for me (Put extra brackets around the tuples)

Try namedtuple() Factory Function for Tuples with Named Fields.

This seems like an issue with how you're using these tuples. Please show the code that generates that error, along with the full traceback.

Please make a [mre] including complete but minimal code and the full error message with traceback. I tried it myself with from enum import Enum and class Pos(tuple, Enum): D1 = (3, 0), but there was no error. I guess the error is coming from a different part of your code, although I don't understand enums very well myself :p

BTW, when you say "variable", I think you mean "element"

The issue has been fixed in Python 3.12.  Until then, wrap your value in a tuple: Pos((3, 0)).

@EthanFurman: The traceback added in the newest revision looks like the questioner is on Python 3.12. Was the fix in a 3.12.x release or something?

@user2357112: Looks like it landed in 3.12.3.
